# Regex for Information Extraction from CS File

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Below is a snapshot of lines from my CS file from C# code and I'm trying to extract fields mandatory or supported fields from my class file.

**1) Is there a way for me to dynamically load the cs file into the .NET application and extract the information out, starting just by loading cs file from file path?**

**2) Following to the question above, I'm currently resorting to extract information out thru Regex.**

First Regex - (m_oSupportedFields.).+?(?=EnumSupported.Mandatory;|EnumSupported.Supported)

and result as below :-
[image: Pic1]

Second Regex - (..+)\=

and result as below :-

[image: Pic2]

What I'm trying to achieve is to extract Persona.Forename, Personal.Surname and other fields by a Regex (one Regex for EnumSupported.Mandatory, and one for EnumSupported.Supported).

Also, I'm trying to cater for malformed line such as

m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Day.Supported=EnumSupported.Supported;
(Note the space between the equal sign)

or

m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Day.Supported =  EnumSupported.Supported;
(Note the double space between)

or even

m_oSupportedFields.Personal.Surname.Supported = 
                EnumSupported.Mandatory;
(Note the Enum is on second line)

Please advice on how should I compile the Regex for such situation.

Thanks.

**UPDATED in TEXTUAL VERSION**

```
 m_oSupportedFields.Personal.Surname.Supported = EnumSupported.Mandatory;
            m_oSupportedFields.Personal.Forename.Supported = EnumSupported.Mandatory;
            m_oSupportedFields.Personal.MiddleName.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
            m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Day.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
            m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Month.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
            m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Year.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
```

Comment: I see why you created the pictures of the data, but it makes it hard for us to cut/paste the data into our test regex examples. Can you provide a textual version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from each line, you want to extract the part after `m_oSupportedFields.` and before `.Supported =`, as well as the part after the `=`. And you want to ignore only blank spaces before the `=`, but any whitespace after the `=`.

Your regular expression will be: `^m_oSupportedFields\.([\w\.]+)\.Supported *=\s*(EnumSupported\.\w+);`

Omit the `^` if you don't want to require that the string start at the beginning of a line.

Using C#, you can access the match groups like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string regex = @"^m_oSupportedFields\.([\w\.]+)\.Supported *=\s*(EnumSupported\.\w+);";
string input = @"m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Day.Supported=EnumSupported.Supported";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, regex))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Captures[0].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(m.Captures[1].ToString());
}

// Console:

// Personal.DOB.Day
// EnumSupported.Supported
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is there a way for me to dynamically load the cs file into the .NET application and extract the information out, starting just by loading cs file from file path?

Possibly, there is the .Net Compiler as a Service which is now used by VS2015 ([Overview](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview)). Look into creating a [Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Semantic-Analysis).

> extract Persona.Forename, Personal.Surname and other fields by a Regex (one Regex for EnumSupported.Mandatory, and one for EnumSupported.Supported).

To create a pattern, one can be very general or one can be very specific on what needs to be captured. As one makes the pattern to be more general, the pattern complexity increases along with the supporting code to extract the data.

**Capture into Enumerable Dynamic Entities**

This is a specific pattern that takes the results and places them into Linq set of dynamic entities. ** Note that it handles the possible line split**

```
string data = @"
m_oSupportedFields.Personal.Surname.Supported =
EnumSupported.Mandatory;
 m_oSupportedFields.Personal.Forename.Supported=EnumSupported.Mandatory;
m_oSupportedFields.Personal.MiddleName.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Day.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Month.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
m_oSupportedFields.Personal.DOB.Year.Supported = EnumSupported.Supported;
";

string pattern = @"
Personal\.                          # Anchor for match
(?<Full>                            # Grouping for Or condition
   (?<Name>[^.]+)                   # Just the name
  |                                 # Or
   (?<Combined>[^.]+\.[^.]+)        # Name/subname
)                                   # End Or Grouping
(?=\.Supported)                     # Look ahead to anchor to Supported (does not capture)
\.Supported
\s*=                                # Possible whitespace and =
[\s\r\n]*EnumSupported\.
(?<SupportType>Mandatory|Supported) # Capture support type";

// Ignore Pattern whitespace allows us to comment the pattern instead of having
// it on oneline. It does not affect regex pattern processing in anyway.
Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => new
                    {
                       FullName   = mt.Groups["Full"].Value,
                       IsName     = mt.Groups["Name"].Success,
                       IsCombined = mt.Groups["Combined"].Success,
                       Type       = mt.Groups["SupportType"].Value
                    })
```

The results look like this:

[image]

Note that it can determine if the *name* extracted is from a **single** like (ForeName) or **double** from (DOB.Day) and captures either into the named capture "FullName" with the "Name" and "Combined" capturings used as "Is-As" booleans.